# Find $N$ given a sequence $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> In the sequence {$a_n$}, $$a_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}}{n-1} \, , \quad n \ge 3$$
>   If $a_1+a_2 \ne 0$ and the sum of the first $N$ terms is $12(a_1+a_2)$, find $N$.

Kind of lost on where to start with this one. My initial thought was, $$\sum^{N}_{n=3}\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}}{n-1}=12(a_1+a_2)$$ $$\sum^{N}_{n=3}\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}}{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2)+\frac{1}{3}(a_1+a_2+a_3)...$$but someting seems wrong here, or I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: Look at writing the first few terms in terms of $a_1+a_2$ and see if you can find a pattern.  For instance, clearly $a_3=\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$; now $a_4=\frac13(a_1+a_2+a_3) =$...?

Comment: I see that in the first few terms but I dont see how to associate it with $12(a_1+a_2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  S_2 &= a_1+a_2 \\
  S_n &= a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n \\
  a_{n+1} &= \frac{a_1+\ldots+a_{n}}{n} \\
  &= \frac{S_n}{n} \\
  S_{n+1} &= S_{n}+\frac{S_n}{n} \\
  &= \frac{n+1}{n} S_{n} \\
  &= \frac{n+1}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{2} S_{2} \\
  &= \frac{n+1}{2} S_2 \\
  S_{N} &= \frac{N}{2} S_2 \\
  &= \frac{N(a_1+a_2)}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Also $\forall n\ge 3$, $$a_{n}=\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}$$

Comment: N is supposed to have an actual integral value that I am supposed to be able to find from the information I have been given.

Comment: Solve $\dfrac{N}{2}=12$

Comment: Oh! I see! Thank you so much!

Comment: elegant approach !

Comment: Wouldn't $S_3=a_1+a_2$? and $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_{n-1}$? or am I mistaken?

Comment: $$S_3=a_1+a_2+a_3=a_1+a_2+\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}=\frac{3}{2}(a_1+a_2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$a_1$
$a_2$
$a_3=\dfrac{a_1+a_2}2$
$a_4=\dfrac {a_1+a_2+(a_1+a_2)}2$
$a_4=\dfrac{a_1+a_2}2$

Similarly, $a_3=a_4=a_5=a_6=\ldots$

Sum up to $n$ numbers is $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots+a_n$

$s=a_1+a_2+(n-2)\cdot a_3$

$s=\dfrac n2(a_1+a_2)$

So $n=12\cdot2=24$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your answers.